# Instant install of wordpress

Tags: customization, ftp, installation

I just think about that... maybe it exist...you will tell me...

Wordpressis a beautifull software, and the thing i like the most, is the instant install of the theme and plugin...

So i though, why not have a onefile.html upload, and install wordpress ITSELF utomaticly fron the svn instead of having to upload a whole buch of file that take a looong time, and sometime failed...

Maybe that file, will just select the language and the name of the folder...

Or maybe, it exist ?...

I know that the database must be done before... i do it, it's just the folder with 1000 files that weight 10 mg that bug me... autoinstall as plugin !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: You can use WordPress QI - http://wpquickinstall.com/download/**

Not all servers can run SVN, and servers which have problem in WP 5minute install, can't be cope up with another solution because there is no solution, sometimes server settings are to blame.

That said, on a server where everything works fine for a regular installation, WordPress install can be automated by how you want it (by uploading a single file and loading that in the browser provided that you provide database connection details to it somehow.

Comment: where i ca get that script... i have only ftp access to the server

Comment: What I meant was that it is do-able and probably you can find something you can use if you can do some search (someone might have done it already).

Comment: Afaik, cPanel's "Fantastico" (or whatever it's called) has WP 3.x now. Also, I think it could be useful to have a single-file install honestly. Look at SMF's (Simple Machine Forums) examples ;)

Comment: i have google... but dont really know the right wording

Comment: i have try those "panel", but more complicated i have to login and do multiple steps..

Comment: @marc-andre Check my answer! I have updated it with just what you need ;)

Comment: A-MA-ZING, PER-FECT! 10/10 and a vimeo of how to used it !... icing on cake; http://vimeo.com/5768560

Answer (score 2):

You can automagically copy files from SVN, but there are steps that will always require some sort of human interaction, such as the initial database setup.

That said, a WordPress install is [totally scriptable](http://www.linode.com/stackscripts/view/?StackScriptID=12).